# Why does the download size of applications increase when downloading from the Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I recently downloaded an app from the Google Play Store and found that it is larger than when downloaded from the site.

[image: Site]
[image: PlayStore]

Why does the volume of applications increase when downloading from the Play Store?

I'm also aware that the common method to infect end-users is software bundlers. installs are typically triggered by bundlers that offer software you might be interested in and
combine them with adware or other monetizing methods .

Comment: Possibly because of [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle). The listing on the web doesn't know which bundles need to be downloaded for your specific device.

Comment: Google does not bundle anything into downloaded apps that does not belong to the app. If an app contains adware or malware then it was uploaded in this state to Google.

Comment: Is it the same version of the app? It'd be better if you share links.